# asp.net - Button event does not fire up

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, button

I have a search button on my page that runs a query on a DB, pulls out and displays some entries in a table, and for each entry I create a button. It looks something like this:

```
List<Friend> friends = SearchFriend(searchStr);
foreach (Friend f in friends)
{
    TableCell addCell = new TableCell(), nameCell = new TableCell();

    addCell.Text = "";
    if (!f.IsMyFriend)
    {
            LinkButton addFriendBtn = new LinkButton();
            addFriendBtn.Text = "Add as Friend";
            addFriendBtn.Click += new EventHandler(addFriendBtn_Click);
            addFriendBtn.ID = "add_" + f.ID.ToString();

            addCell.Controls.Add(addFriendBtn);
    }
    nameCell.Text = f.Name;

    TableRow row = new TableRow();
    row.Cells.Add(addCell);
    row.Cells.Add(nameCell);

    SearchFriendTable.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Problem is that the LinkButton event does not fire when it is pressed (changing LinkButton to a simple Button does not fix this either).

This is the html that I get in this portion:

```
<td><a id="ctl00_contentPH_add_2" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$contentPH$add_2','')">Add as Friend</a></td>
```

Also - when I put a breakpoint on Page_Load I do see the __EVENTTARGET with this control's id in it - however the event never starts running.

Any clues?
Thanks.

Comment: Show you page load code, pls.

Comment: It's empty :-O.

protected void Page\_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Himadri's answer:

Dynamically added controls need to be rewired in page init.  Then the event will fire.  I had a very similar issue [Dynamically loaded Controls in a wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315102/dynamically-loaded-controls-in-a-wizard)

Answer (score 1):

Where and when did you created that button?

If you dynamically create Buttons and want to listen to a event you have to create that button in the PageInit event. Always! So do not use if(!IsPostback)

Comment: You're right - I'm not creating the button inside the Page\_Load but rather inside of another event. How can I fix it then? I did not understand the "if(!IsPostBack)" part of your answer...

Comment: You have to create the buttons in the Page_Init event. With !IsPostback I mean that you have to recreate the button every request. Usually you initializes a Grid or similar only once - with the !IsPostback check

Answer (score 1):

Try with this.

```
<td><a id="ctl00_contentPH_add_2" href="javascript:__doPostBack('<%=ct100_contentPH_add_2.ClientId %>','')">Add as Friend</a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add event handler for the link buttons and handle those events.

```
 if (!f.IsMyFriend)
    {
            LinkButton addFriendBtn = new LinkButton();
            addFriendBtn.Text = "Add as Friend";
            addFriendBtn.Click += new EventHandler(addFriendBtn_Click);
            addFriendBtn.ID = "add_" + f.ID.ToString();
            addFriendBtn.Click += new EventHandler(addFriendBtn_Click);
            addCell.Controls.Add(addFriendBtn);
    }
```

**the event:**

```
  protected void addFriendBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            LinkButton lnk = (LinkButton)sender;
            // do your coding
    }
```

Comment: I have an event handler, of course :). Problem is that the code inside of it never starts running.